# How to add scope null for all unwanted API's in MSAL angular configuration

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

We have an angular application, which calls multiple API's. Currently we are just interested in injecting b2c access token to only two API's and want to avoid for other API's.

Our API's are as follows

```
https://testdomain.com/onprem/proxy/handler/api/account/someendpoint
https://testdomain.com/onprem/proxy/handler/something/api/account/someendpoint
https://testdomain.com/onprem/something/api/account/endpoint
https://testdomain.com/cloud/api/app1/something/endpoint
```

Since the structure of the API calls are not similar. we have our current implementation as below

```
export const protectedResourceMap: [string, string[]][] = [
['/cloud/api/app1/account/gettestaccount',['scope1']],
['/cloud/api/app2/account/getanotheraccount',['scope2']],
['/onprem/*/*/*/*/*', null],
['/onprem/*/*/*/*/*/*', null],
['/onprem/*/*/*/*', null]
]
```

So MSAL Interceptor is matching the req.url  with protectedresourcemap using **minimatch**.
In the above example I specified 3 different patterns with `scopes:null` . So `getScopesForEndpoint()` will be called 5 times, even though out of those 5 calls, 3 are unwanted.

Could some please suggest a better approach to add url's to `protectedResourceMap` will `scopes: null`, so that I can reduce the calls to `getScopesForEndpoint()` and improve the performance of front-end app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`getScopesForEndpoint` will always be called, even before the change to minimatch. We can look at improving `getScopesForEndpoint` to not call minimatch if `null` is set, if there are concerns with performance of that in this scenario.

Comment: Is it possible, first to check api against protected resource, if the api call matches any of the protected resources, then call the ```getScopesForEndpoint```?

Comment: `getScopesForEndpoint` does the check to see if a given url is a protected resource.